# Как вывести корректно часть строки без символов � и без ошибок в mb_substr?

Tags: php

У меня стоит phpStorm, на который я установил скачанный интрепретатор, если дело в php.ini , то объясните пожалуйста как мне его создать, где создать и как подключить и что в нем написать, чтобы mb_string заработала?

```
$inputString = '->11гe+20∆∆A+4µcњil->5•Ћ®†Ѓ p+5f-7Ќ¬f pro+10g+1悦ra->58->44m+1*m+2a喜er!';

//$res = mb_substr($inputString,11,10);

$res2 = substr($inputString,11,10);

//print($res);
print($res2);
```

функция mb_substr возвращает ошибку -
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_substr() in C:\Program Files\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.mini\fii.php:59 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\OSPanel\domains\bitrix.mini\fii.php on line 59

$res2 возвращает строку с пороклятыми символами ��
��∆A+4µ

Как вывести корректно часть строки без символов � и без ошибок в mb_substr?

Comment: Проверьте в `php.ini` строку `extension=mbstring`.

Comment: Попробуйте перед использованием `mb_substr ();` явно указать `mb_internal_encoding ("UTF-8");`